# How to set up blueeyes project in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm having trouble setting up [this](https://github.com/thanhiro/blueeyes-example) project using SBT.

It does not resolve [blueeyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes) dependency when I type sbt run:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.reportgrid#blueeyes_2.9.1.RC1;0.4.19: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.reportgrid:blueeyes_2.9.1.RC1:0.4.19 (.../blueeyes-example/build.sbt#L19-22)
[warn]        +- com.foo:blueeyes-test-api_2.9.1.RC1:0.1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.reportgrid#blueeyes_2.9.1.RC1;0.4.19: not found
```

The BlueEyes project on Github seems abandoned but I hope there's still someone who can help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the documentation of the blueeyes repository, the dependencies should be declares like this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public",
  "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.jdegoes" %% "blueeyes-core"  % "0.6.0",
  "com.github.jdegoes" %% "blueeyes-mongo" % "0.6.0",
  "com.github.jdegoes" %% "blueeyes-json"  % "0.6.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.0" % "runtime"
)
```

your library dependencies look a bit different:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.reportgrid" % "blueeyes_2.9.1.RC1" % "0.4.19" % "compile"
)
```

**UPDATE:**

And scala version needs to be

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
```

instead of

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.1.RC1"
```

Comment: This gives me more errors:
[error]sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.jdegoes#blueeyes-core_2.9.1.RC1;0.6.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.jdegoes#blueeyes-mongo_2.9.1.RC1;0.6.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.jdegoes#blueeyes-json_2.9.1.RC1;0.6.0: not found

Comment: @SvyatoslavIlinskiy probably because there are no modules for scala version `2.9.1.RC1`. Set `scalaVersion := 2.9.1`

Comment: This is what I get now: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.9.1;7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Comment: I have no idea why it requires scalaz

Comment: I really appreciate that you're hellping me :) Thank you!

Comment: The bueeyes lib seems to require scalaz. I guess, that's what you get when you fiddle with 3 years old libraries ;) I'd suggest you have a look at the [sonatype repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/com/github/jdegoes/) and try the versions stored under `2.9.2` and/or `2.9.3` and see if you get anywhere.

Comment: Also the library is in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.blueeyes/blueeyes/0.3.27. Worth to research what deps are correct.